# Is there a class to read in a CSV file in the build for an iPhone?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is there a class to read in an attached CSV file in the build for an iPhone?

thanks

I am trying to reading in a CSV file that holds 200 rows and 10 columns.
The first row is the header.

I want to be able to search through a column, for an item, and pull all the info for that particular row.

Comment: What do you want to do to it? Add it to the bundle? Parse it?